# Pygame square not showing up because of sprites

Tags: pygame, square

I try to print a square for use as a hitbox because the collision detection doesn't work on images. But when I try to draw a test square in setup it doesn't appear. I have tried moving the command, and changing it but nothing worked. And that is only for the square. The images appear and move perfectly. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the sprites because without them everything works perfectly.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
fps = 30
fpsclock=pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

x = 275
y = 375
BulletX = x + 10
BulletY = y - 15
color = (250,210,240)
ship_img = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
ship = pygame.transform.scale(ship_img,(32,32))
bullet_img = pygame.image.load('bullet (2).png')
bullet = pygame.transform.scale(bullet_img,(12,12))

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    # limit frames per second
    fpsclock.tick(fps)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed() #key inputs
    if key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 5
    if key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 5

    # clear the display
    window.fill(0)


    
    window.blit(ship,(x,y))
    pygame.draw.rect(window,color,pygame.rect(200,200,30,30))
    window.blit(bullet,(BulletX,BulletY))
    
    BulletY = BulletY - 20
    if(BulletY <= -10):
        BulletY = y - 10
        BulletX = x + 10
    

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your code is a lowercase 'r' instead of of uppercase one. Change the appropriate line to:

```
    pygame.draw.rect(window, color, pygame.Rect(200,200,30,30) )
```

and have fun implementing the collision.